# adjusting font size of directlabels for lattice with default placement method

Tags: r, font-size, label, direct-labels

When attempting to adjust the font size in `directlabels`, using `list(cex=2)`, the function undesirably adds labels to every single point.

```
library(lattice)
library(directlabels)
foo <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=c(1:5, (1:5)^2), z=c(1:10))
direct.label( xyplot( y + z ~ x, foo, type=c('l','g') ),
              list(cex=2) )
```

I'd prefer the default label placement (with one label per group) that comes with the ordinary call:

```
direct.label( xyplot( y + z ~ x, foo, type=c('l','g') ) )
```

Specifying a position method like `first.points` below, gives the desired one label per group, but this is not the same default label placement method I am after.

```
direct.label( xyplot( y + z ~ x, foo, type=c('l','g') ),
              list("first.points", cex=2) )
```

Does anyone know which which position method reproduces the default automatic placement method? Or is there another way to change label font size without specifying the position method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method used in this case is `"lines2"`:

```
direct.label(xyplot( y + z ~ x, foo, type=c('l','g') ),
             list("lines2", list(cex=2)) )
```

[image]

FYI, I figured that out by taking a quick look at `getAnywhere("direct.label.trellis")`, which pointed me towards `panel.superpose.dl()`. To learn what method *it* selected in the line reading

```
if (is.null(method)) 
    method <- default.picker("trellis")
```

I did `debug(panel.superpose.dl)`, ran the code in your second code block, and stepped through with the debugger until I could check which method got picked by `default.picker()`.

Comment: Many thanks for showing your thought process. This suggests that there is no simple way to maintain automation of method selection while adjusting font size, but it does narrow the answer down to a few default functions including `lines2`, `maxvar.qp`, and `maxvar.points`, which show up inside the `get("defaultpf.trellis")` call from  `default.picker("trellis")`. Whew!

Comment: Yeah, it really shouldn't be that hard to have both automatic/heuristic selection of placement method **and** slightly tweaked graphical parameters. Might be worth a note to the package author, especially if you dig a little deeper and can suggest a simple fix.